# Python Function: that replies YES or NO -something is wrong

Tags: python, function, command

Test that the year passed is greater than or equal to 1582.

```
def gregyear():

    try:
        year =raw_input("Pick a year greater than or equal to 1582. It has to be divisible by four.)\n")
        year =float(year)
        leapyear = "Yes"
    except:
        print "please, only numbers"
    else:
        year =float(year)
        if  year >= 1582:
            if year % 4:
                print year
                leapyear= "Yes"
            else:
                leapyear= "No"
        else:
            print "Wrong... print a year greater than 1582"


    return leapyear

gregyear()
print "leapyear is  "+ leapyear +"."
```

Comment: What is your question? All you've done is post some code.

Comment: Please understand python basics first. It would be a great opportunity for you to go through the stack trace and figure out what is going on. Example: start off with `leapyear` is not defined in the scope of the print at the end of the code. (A good starting point to understand how functions return value, etc.. )

Answer (score 1):

First, in Python, 0 is falsey, and all other numbers are truthy. So, when you do this:

```
if year % 4:
```

… that will trigger if `year % 4` is anything except `0`, meaning if the year is *not* divisible by 4. So your logic is backward.

---

Second, while `gregyear` does return a value, you ignore that return value If you want to use it, you have to store it:

```
leapyear = gregyear()
```

---

Third, you can't add strings to numbers, so this will raise a `TypeError`:

```
print "leapyear is  "+ leapyear +"."
```

What you probably wanted is to either pass the strings and number to `print` to magically concatenate together while printing, like this:

```
print "leapyear is", leapyear, "."
```

Notice that I removed the extra spaces, because `print` with commas automatically puts spaces between its arguments.

However, a better way to write this is with string formatting:

```
print "leapyear is {}.".format(leapyear)
```

---

As a side note, you're also missing the rule that makes 1700, 1800, and 1900 not leap years (while 1600 and 2000 are).